# How to add body element in facebook's reactjs my-app?

Tags: html, dom, reactjs, reactive-programming

I want to add a background image on Facebook's react.js **my-app**. I can do this by setting a background image to a div element. But my div only covers half of the page. Which is why my image is not fulling occupying the page.

Instead, I want to do this on a body element. But how to add a body element and set a background image to it?

I tried this, but its not working in App.js file of **my-app**

```
<body background="http://i.imgur.com/DaNQJ6I.jpg"></body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I cannot add a background image on app.js or  app.css files of react framework. However, I tried to do it on index.html. This worked perfectly to me.

So, please add background images on index.html If you are unable to do it in app.js or app.css.

And also, future readers, If you have found a way to do it, feel free to answer the question, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED]

Css-tricks.com provides a quite cool solution of the full page images:

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

I used this example for my React implementation with the useEffect (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Note: background-size replaced by backgroundSize when the style is setted.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import img from "./test.jpg";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.background = `url('${img}') no-repeat center center fixed`;
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    document.body.style.webkitBackgroundSize = "cover";
  }, []);
  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to explain your code and why your answer works?

Comment: @PawaraSiriwardhane I added to the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `style`:

```
<body style={ bodyStyle }></body>
```

And `bodyStyle` should look like:

```
var bodyStyle = { backgroundImage: 'url(http://i.imgur.com/DaNQJ6I.jpg)' };
```

Comment: This is not gonna work. For some reason, adding style into any of the html elements in reactjs will display a blank page.

Comment: If `<body>` is also part of your React code, then you would need to do it in react way: `<body style={bodyStyle}>` and `var bodyStyle = { backgroundImage: 'url(http://i.imgur.com/DaNQJ6I.jpg)' }`

Comment: Displaying a blank page!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. The actual work is done in componentDidMount(). So technically, you could add this on about any component. Like, you could put it on a navbar or even in the layout.

For my projects, I created a  component. Add it to your layout (or where ever) and it should work.

Good luck!

```js
export default class BodyStyle extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { style } = this.props;

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ];
    for ( var key in style ) {
      body.style[ key ] = style[ key ];
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <span ref="BodyStyle"/>;
  }
};
```